# kitchen sink not working

Tags: customization

seems the kitchen sink, and sidebar show/hide links, are not working. i have upgraded to latest release with no such luck in fixing problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have something making your site use jQuery 1.5.0? jQuery 1.5 is not backwards compatible, and won't work.